# Sort array of strings composed of numbers

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following array which contains strings;

```
let data = ["2018-1", "2018-5", "2018-11", "2018-2", "2018-10", "2018-12"];
```

these strings are composed of number (year and month).

Can you tell me why didn't work following function for sorting? I need sort this array from latest date to oldest. In this case from **"2018-12"** to **"2018-1".**

I am using lodash in whole project so I try use it here as well.

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, function(i) {
  var x = i.split("-").map(Number);
  return [x[0], x[1]];
});
```

can you tell me why this code doesn't work and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us, what "_this code doesn't work_" means?

Comment: Why not use the built-in JavaScript `.sort()` method on the array? It's more flexible than the lodash sort.

Comment: the missing of leading zero for month smaller than 10 makes sorting complicated. the most easy solution would using a leading zero for month numbers and use the date string directly.

Comment: The first error that I got is `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`
What do you mean with "this code doesn't work", show me the error, please

Comment: the problem with this question is, you have the date in a niche sortable format, but you change it to a unsortable format for the final result. the question now is a philosophical approach to change the original given well formated back to a wrong, but needed, or just to use the well formatted date and later change the date to the wanted format.

Comment: Next time, please don't tag "lodash" if you're looking for vanilla code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a few more dates as proof.

```js
let data = ["2018-1", "2018-5", "2018-11", "2018-2", "2018-10", "2018-12", "2017-5", "2019-12"];

var result = data.sort((a, b) => {
  var n1 = a.split("-");
  var n2 = b.split("-");
  n1 = parseInt(n1[0]) * 100 + parseInt(n1[1]);
  n2 = parseInt(n2[0]) * 100 + parseInt(n2[1]);
  return n1 - n2;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `sortBy` doesn't support compound keys, so your array key is converted to a string. A workaround is either to provide two separate keys:

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, [
    x => Number(x.split('-')[0]),
    x => Number(x.split('-')[1]),
]);
```

or synthesize a numeric one:

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, x => {
    x = x.split('-');
    return Number(x[0]) * 1000 + Number(x[1])
});
```

Finally, you can take a risk and try `Date.parse`:

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, Date.parse)
```

which looks neat, but requires some cross-browser testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the splitted deltas for year and month.

```js
var data = ["2018-1", "2018-5", "2018-11", "2018-2", "2018-10", "2018-12", "2017-5", "2019-12"],
    result = data.sort((a, b) => {
        var aa = a.split("-"),
            bb = b.split("-");

        return aa[0] - bb[0] || aa[1] - bb[1];
    });

console.log(result);
```